# How would you use multiple mysql queries in C#

Tags: c#, mysql

```
try
{
    string strConnection = "host=bla; database=twhalen_storage; username=twhalen_software; password=bla!;";
    MySqlConnection conSQL = new MySqlConnection(strConnection);
    MySqlCommand mycommand = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM twhalen_storage.users WHERE username= '" + this.username_txt.Text + "'AND password= '" + this.password_txt.Text + "';", conSQL);
    MySqlDataReader myReader;
    conSQL.Open();
    myReader = mycommand.ExecuteReader();
    int count = 0;
    while (myReader.Read())
    {
        count = count + 1;
    }
    if (count == 1)
    {
        this.Hide();
        Form2 f2 = new Form2();
        f2.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("go away");
    conSQL.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

How would I do multiple mysql queries using code similar to this?

Comment: You may be interested in `SELECT COUNT(*)`

Comment: This will be vulernable to sql injection attacks. It's practically begging to get hacked. Not only that, but it's storing passwords in plain text. Those are two of the biggest security sins out there.

Comment: You want to do multiple independents queries or query that contains multiple queries?

Comment: Multiple independent queries

Comment: also joel, i'm just using this to learn. Not for real use outside of my own.

Comment: Okay so what exactly is it that is preventing you from using multiple queries? And, if you learn to do things correctly (parameterized queries) then you won't have to unlearn bad habits later on.

Comment: for example `count++;` or `count += 1;` are better habits to train yourself hereinafter